# Data control from textbox and inverted day/month values

Tags: forms, excel, vba, date, textbox

I need to check if the date entered in a textbox is valid. It has to be a single textbox, so no workaround this way.
Now, I have this code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim dataAnalisi As Date
If IsDate(txtDataAnalisi.Value) Then
dataAnalisi = txtDataAnalisi.Value
    Dim giornoAnalisi, meseAnalisi As Integer
    giornoAnalisi = Format(dataAnalisi, "dd")
    meseAnalisi = Format(dataAnalisi, "mm")
    If giornoAnalisi <= 31 And meseAnalisi <= 12 Then
        Call arrayList(dataAnalisi)
        Unload Me
    Else
        GoTo DateError
    End If
Else
DateError:
    MsgBox "Inserire una data formattata correttamente!", vbCritical, "Errore nell'inserimento!"
    txtDataAnalisi.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Sorry if it has text in Italian. The function works decently, the only problem is that if I input for instance 11/14/12 (where the date is dd/mm/yy and 14 was a mistype) it inverts the day and month values. Instead, I want the sub to tell the user to check his input again! Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: What is Call arrayList calling? Can you provide a example of your sheet?

Comment: Even though it has to be a single textbox, you might use a datepicker that pops-up to absolutely control the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are variations of this question every month or so.  I am convinced that Excel will treat a date that is a valid American date as an American date.  I have thought this for many years but others disagree.

I use functions like the one below which check for formats I believe Excel will misinterpret and convert them to an unambiguous format.

I use the English abbreviations for months.  I believe French is the only language that does not permit three character abbreviations for months so perhaps you have your own set.  You will have to adapt that part of the routine to your requirement.

Hopes this helps.

```
Function MyDateValue(ByVal DateIn As String, ByRef DateOut As Date) As Boolean

  ' DateIn is a value to be checked as a valid date.
  ' If it is a valid date, DateOut is set to its value and the function
  ' returns True.

  ' Excel misinterprets dates such as "4/14/11" as 14 April 2011.  This routine
  ' checks for such dates and, if necessary, changes them to an unambiguous
  ' format before calling IsDate and DateValue.

  Dim DatePart() As String
  Dim MonthNum As Long

  Const MonthAbbr As String = "janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec"

  ' Replace popular delimiters with Microsoft standard
  DateIn = Replace(DateIn, "-", "/")
  DateIn = Replace(DateIn, "\", "/")

  DatePart = Split(DateIn, "/")
  If UBound(DatePart) = 2 Then
    ' DateStg is three values separated by delimiters
    ' Check middle part
    If IsNumeric(DatePart(1)) Then
      MonthNum = Val(DatePart(1))
      If MonthNum >= 1 And MonthNum <= 12 Then
        ' Middle part could be numeric month
        ' Convert to format Excel does not misinterpret
         'Debug.Assert False
        DatePart(1) = Mid(MonthAbbr, ((MonthNum - 1) * 3) + 1, 3)
        DateIn = Join(DatePart, "-")
        If IsDate(DateIn) Then
          DateOut = DateValue(DateIn)
          MyDateValue = True
          Exit Function
        End If
      Else
        ' Middle part cannot be a month
        'Debug.Assert False
        MyDateValue = False
        Exit Function
      End If
    Else
      'Debug.Assert False
      ' The middle part is not a number.  It could be a month abbreviation
      MonthNum = InStr(1, MonthAbbr, LCase(DatePart(1)))
      If MonthNum = 0 Then
        ' The middle portion is neither a month number nor a month abbreviation
        Debug.Assert False
        MyDateValue = False
      Else
        ' The middle portion is a month abbreviation.
        ' Excel will handle date correctly
        'Debug.Assert False
        MonthNum = (MonthNum - 1) / 3 + 1
        DateIn = Join(DatePart, "-")
        If IsDate(DateIn) Then
        'Debug.Assert False
          DateOut = DateValue(DateIn)
          MyDateValue = True
          Exit Function
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Else
    '    Debug.Assert False
    ' Use IsDate for other formats
    If IsDate(DateIn) Then
       ' Debug.Assert False
      DateOut = DateValue(DateIn)
      MyDateValue = True
      Exit Function
    Else
      '  Debug.Assert False
      MyDateValue = False
    End If
  End If

End Function
```